# Call API during Claims Transformation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, claims, blazor-server-side

I am adding claims transformation into my Blazor (server-side) application. I am creating an HTTP Web API service using DI. Below is the start up code.

```
services.AddHttpClient<IAPIClient, APIClient>();
services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsLoader>();
```

I would like to then use claims transformation to call this Web API once I am authenticated. Which looks like:

```
public class ClaimsLoader : IClaimsTransformation
{
   private readonly HttpClient _apiClient;
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpAccessor;

   public ClaimsLoader(IHttpContextAccessor httpAccessor, HttpClient apiClient)
   {
      _httpAccessor = httpAccessor;
      _apiClient = apiClient;
   }
   public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
   {
      var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
      var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
             identity.Claims,
             identity.AuthenticationType,
             identity.NameClaimType,
             identity.RoleClaimType);

      ...claims Web API call
       return new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
   }
}
```

This is the Web API client setup:

```
public class APIClient : IAPIClient
{
   private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
   public APIClient(IHttpContextAccessor httpAccessor, HttpClient client, IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      var accessToken = httpAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration["Api_Location"]);
      _httpClient = client;
   }
....
}
```

The problem arises because I don't understand DI that well. I want to use the APIClient that I created before it but, I am not sure how to pass that into the ClaimsLoader. I assume that it would be something like:

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpAccessor;
private readonly IAPIClient _apiClient;

public ClaimsLoader(IHttpContextAccessor httpAccessor, IAPIClient apiClient)
{
   _httpAccessor = httpAccessor;
   _apiClient = apiClient;
}
```

But trying this cause the app to hang when starting. What am I missing? Ihave the API call create and working so that it will return a list of claims.

**UPDATE 10/2/2019**

I think I have found the issue is related to an infinite loop caused by the following line:

```
var accessToken = _httpAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;
```

This causes a call to AuthenticateAsync which in turn then calls this line again. Is there a way to get the Bearer token differently so as not to cause this loop?

Comment: is it wired up as a singleton in startup, post your startup code, you could create a new instance just to check it

Comment: Just made an update to the original text. The startup is the first code block.